# Security - how to implement blocking functionality between users in android app so that they can't reach each other anymore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on an android app which is using Firestore as its database. It is a chatting/dating app similar to Tinder, searching for users nearby to chat with. so, guys, I need your help in "blocking user" feature like if user1 block user2 due to any reason I want to show that blocked user2 in a list of blocked users activity inside the user1 app and obviously both the users should not see each other anywhere in the app not even in the searches just like tinder.

And later on, if the user1 decides to unblock user2, user2 should start appearing on the searches again.

So please help me out guys. i'm stuck here and don't know how to accomplish it. so please help and thank you guys in advance. i know you will help me out for sure.

Comment: Please provide more clarity by adding how much you have done and the code snippets for developers otherwise people will downvote for opinion based question

Comment: thanks a lot i will keep that in mind next time i will ask any question. but if can see  below a person understands my question and answered it. that's what i what i wanted. but  you are right too. i should have been more specific. thanks anyway.

Comment: Everyone was in this same place once bro :D take it positively happy coding :)

Comment: yup everyone gets in the same every once in a while. and yes we should always have a positive mind whether it is life or coding. thanks and happy coding to you too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have a collection of users in which every user is a document within `users` collection, to solve this I recommend you to add a new property of type `array` under each user object like this:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- users (collection)
        |
        --- uid (document)
             |
             --- blockedUsers: ["friendUid", "friendUid"]
             |
             --- //other user properties
```

When you are searching the nearby users, add each user that you find to a list. Having a list of all the nearby users you can now check if the user that is searching the nearby users is in the `blockedUsers` list or not. You can achieve this using a Query that looks like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
Query query = rootRef.collection("users").whereArrayContains("blockedUsers", uid);
```

In this way you can display to the user only the nearby users that have or have not added him to blocked list.

Comment: thanks a lot man thats what i wanted. i kept thinking how to do it for almost a whole day. and you provided how to do it so thanks a lot man. i'll use your logic in my app and if i had any problems i'll come here and bother you. so thanks and you might hear from me again man. and thanks again.

Comment: @AlexMamo  Even we stored friedsUid as an array list in a document and if we want to query it only works with 10 array items right?

Comment: @IsuruBandara You can use the `in` operator to combine up to [10 equality (==) clauses](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any) on the same field with a logical `OR`.